# Excel Solver Function

Tags: excel, vba, solver

Hi assuming I have some cell 'A1' and some cell 'A2' both dependent on another cell 'C1'.

I would like to make the values of 'A1' and 'A2' equal by changing 'C1'.

I thought something along the lines of:

```
SolverOk SetCell:="A1", ValueOf:=Range("A2").Value, MaxMinVal:=3, ByChange:="C1" Engine:=1
```

Now the issue is that it will solve for the initial value of "A2", and won't account for its changing value.

I tried to rectify this with a for loop:

```
  do while not Range("A1").Value = Range("A2".Value
     Call Solver()
     loop
```

But it stops after the first iteration.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thanks all!

Comment: Add a constraint that A1=A2...

Comment: Make another cell as `=ABS(A1-A2)` and minimise that value by changing C1